# Convert Ecto.DateTime to milliseconds

Tags: time, elixir, ecto, milliseconds

In Elixir, what is the best way to convert an `Ecto.DateTime` into integer milliseconds?

I saw [this example](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-convert-ecto-datetime-to-unix-timestamps/1165/3) and believe I have adapted it for milliseconds, but I want to know if there is any caveat to my approach.

```
(((datetime
   |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl
   |> :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds
   |> Kernel.-(62167219200)) * 1000000) + datetime.usec)
|> div(1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculations looks correct to me. You improve this slightly using more pipes:

```
datetime = Ecto.DateTime.utc(:usec)

datetime
|> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl
|> :calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds
|> Kernel.-(62167219200)
|> Kernel.*(1000000)
|> Kernel.+(datetime.usec)
|> div(1000)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
1472105945416
```

You may also want to replace that constant value with `:calendar.datetime_to_gregorian_seconds({{1970, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}})`, possibly storing it in a module attribute so that there's no performance hit, like how [timex does](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/9e20b5d5155ffb181a2df6c1be99c56847f8d272/lib/datetime/erlang.ex#L5).